# function to read json data from file and convert t into a list

Tags: python, json

What code can I write to read python data from a json file I save and then convert it into a list?

Here is some sample code:

```
def read_json_file(filename):
    """
    reads from a json file and saves the result in a list named data
    """
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
        
        
    # INSERT THE MISSING PIECE OF CODE HERE
    
       
        data = json.loads(content)
    return data
```

Comment: `content = fp.read()` ?

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

To import a json file, I recommend using the json libary.
In your example, you would first need to import it.

```
import json
```

Then you can use

```
with open('filename.json', 'r') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)
```

to get the data. Note that load is different from 'loads' (https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). You just need to change 'content'  to 'fp' since that is how you referred to your file.

Note that this code stores returns the json as a dict, not as a list, which is different than what you are asking about, but probably what you want to use not knowing more about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically use the builtin `json` module. Full documentation here : [https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/json.html)

To get a json string from object (any data like list, dict, etc...), use :

```
    import json

    json_str = json.dumps(my_data)  # Get json string representation of my_data
    fp.write(json_str)              # Write json_str string to file fp
```

Once you wrote your file you can read the json string from file with :

```
    json_str = fp.read()
```

And finally turn to a python object :

```
    import json

    my_data = json.loads(json_str)
```